# How to solve ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error:

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I am using symfony2. Actually i have created form using form type. but when i render the form, following error occurred

> **ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView**

Here is my code

**Controller**

```
$profile = new profile();
$myForm = $this->createForm(new ProfileFormType(), $profile);
return $this->render('ProfileBundle:Profle:profile.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $myForm,
    'vendor' => $vendor,
    'productId' => $productId
));
```

**profile.twig.html**

```
<form action="{{ path('profile_new') }}" method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }} id="frmProfile">

    <div class="box-body col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name: </label>
            {{ form_widget(form.firstName, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'Title', 'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            <div class="serverError">{{ form_errors(form.firstName) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name: </label>
            {{ form_widget(form.lastName, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'Title', 'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            <div class="serverError">{{ form_errors(form.lastName) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">User Name: </label>
            {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': { 'placeholder': 'Title', 'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            <div class="serverError">{{ form_errors(form.username) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$myForm->createView();`

Answer (score 4):

Replace `'form' => $myForm` with `'form' => $myForm->createView()`. Function `createView()` will create view of form object.

```
return $this->render('ProfileBundle:Profle:profile.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $myForm->createView(),  // << Add "->createView()"
    'vendor' => $vendor,
    'productId' => $productId
));
```